# Refresh data when opening the file option not working on Excel pivot table

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365, pivot-table

We have an Excel file with a pivot and a data tab. It is stored on the server, and when the user downloads it, a process fills the data tab and changes the pivot's data source to the newly added data. Because of this, I selected the *Refresh data when opening the file option* option, and when I open the file, after clicking the *Enable editing* button, the pivot refreshes and contains the correct data.

However, for some other users it does not work. They hit the *Enable editing*, but the pivot stays empty. If they directly *Refresh* the data in the pivot, the data appears (so no links or names are broken). Also, if they send the same document to someone else, the data appears on opening the file.

My guess is that some local setting on their computer or in their Excel (Microsoft 365 for business) prevents the data from loading, but I have no idea where to start looking. What can cause this issue on their computer?

Answer (score 1):

According to the official article "[Refresh an external data connection in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/refresh-an-external-data-connection-in-excel-1524175f-777a-48fc-8fc7-c8514b984440)":

> Connections to external data may be currently disabled on your
> computer. To refresh the data when you open a workbook, you must
> enable the data connections by using the Trust Center bar, or you must
> place the workbook in a trusted location. For more information, see
> [Add, remove, or modify a trusted location for your files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-remove-or-change-a-trusted-location-7ee1cdc2-483e-4cbb-bcb3-4e7c67147fb4), [Add, remove,
> or view a trusted publisher](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-remove-or-view-a-trusted-publisher-87b3d5a3-b68c-4023-87c4-7cc78a44d7ed), and [View my options and settings in the
> Trust Center](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/view-my-privacy-options-in-the-microsoft-office-trust-center-d672876e-20d3-4ad3-a178-343d044e05c8).

For more information about external content in Office documents, read [Block or unblock external content in Office documents](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/block-or-unblock-external-content-in-office-documents-10204ae0-0621-411f-b0d6-575b0847a795).